# Googlemail.com/gmail.com email normalization

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a register system for my new project. The only problem I have is that @googlemail.com and @gmail.com are recognized as seperate email addresses. Does any one have an idea or some PHP code on how you would change them all from '@googlemail.com' to '@gmail.com'.

```
**Some pseudocode to help you**
    $change = '@gmail.com'
   $email = swap($change,'@googlemail.com', $email);
```

My programming skills are limited, so don't judge the pseudocode.

Comment: well they actully are separate email addresses. what does rewriting them achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use str_replace():

```
$email = 'example@gmail.com';
$email = str_replace('@gmail.com','@googlemail.com',$email);
```

This will transform `example@gmail.com` into `example@googlemail.com`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [stripos()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) to find the string, then [str_ireplace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) to replace gmail with googlemail.

```
if(stripos($email,'@gmail.com')!== false){
    $email = str_ireplace('gmail.com','googlemail.com',$email);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normalizing GMail addresses is not as easy as it seems. GMail has the following features to alter an address:

- Different Domains: gmail, googlemail
- Dots are only used for decoration: my.address@gmail.com and myaddress@gmail.com belong to the same mailbox
- Random Text can be added using '+' sign: my.addres+sometext@gmail.com

  ```
  /**
  * Normalize a GMail Address.
  *
  * Example:
  * my.name.1+ABC123@gmail.com => myname1@gmail.com
  * my.name@googlemail.com => myname@gmail.com
  *
  * @param string $email
  * @return string
  */
  public function normalize ($email)
  {
     foreach (array(
             'gmail.com',
             'googlemail.com'
         ) as $domain) {
         if (substr_count($email, $domain)) {
             $email = preg_replace('/\+.*(@)/i', '\\1', $email);     //removes +ABC123
             $email = explode('@', $email);
             $email[0] = str_replace('.', '', $email[0]);            //remove dots
             $email = implode('@', $email);
             $email = str_replace('@' . $domain, '@gmail.com', $email); //set default domain
         }
  }
  return $email;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Use either [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) or [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

`substr()` is probably the safer option. There's many other ways too.
The `swap()` you're looking for would be `str_replace()` (if you just change `swap` to `str_replace` should do the trick.